# Wordpress, плагин при загрузке делает таблицу

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Пытаюсь писать плагин.
Он при включении создает таблицу. Ниже функция, отвечающая за это.
У меня есть sql. файл с 2-мя таблицами. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать чтобы плагин не создавал таблицу а брал таблицы из файла, или только одну таблицу из файла?

```
function activate () {
        global $wpdb;
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/upgrade-functions.php');
        $table = $this->tbl_city_sdek;
        if ( version_compare(mysql_get_server_info(), '4.1.0', '>=') ) {
            if ( ! empty($wpdb->charset) )
                $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $wpdb->charset";
            if ( ! empty($wpdb->collate) )
                $charset_collate .= " COLLATE $wpdb->collate";
        }
        $sql_table_city_sdek = "
CREATE TABLE `".$wpdb->prefix."city_sdek` (
    `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `country_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `state_code` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `city_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)".$charset_collate.";";

        // Проверка на существование таблицы
        if ( $wpdb->get_var("show tables like '".$table."'") != $table ) {
            dbDelta($sql_table_city_sdek);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, что плагин должен делать то?

Comment: "брал таблицы из файла", не совсем понятно